# Reading strings from the console and storing them in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, input

I am having some confusion on how to store strings in an array. The objective of the program is to take in a number of students and a number of quizzes from the console then calculate the average of said quiz grades per student which is easy enough. Though I am running into some problems when i try to take in the students names(1-10 strings based on the number of students the user gives me). The only way i can think to take this data in is by using a for loop, as the amount of names i need to read in is determined by the users input. I'd like to store the names in an array but i am unsure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Code below.

```
int main()
{
    int students = 0;
    getStudents(students);

    int quizzes = 0;
    getQuizzes(quizzes);

    char* studentArray = new char[students];
    int* quizArray = new int[quizzes];
    double* studentAverage = new double[students];

    char student_name[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the students name: ";
        cin.get (student_name, 20);
        cin.ignore(' ','\n');
        studentArray[i]=student_name;
        for(int j = 0; j < quizzes; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter quiz " << j+1 << ":";
            cin >> quizArray[j];
        }
        studentAverage[i] = calculateAvergage(quizArray,quizzes);
    }
```

^ the main program. the problem is occurring in the outer for-loop. I'm being forced to take in the names inside the loop because i can't know how many names to take in until runtime. I also have to display the names later in the program after the loop is finished so i can't just do a simple cout<< inside the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < students; i++)
{
    cout << studentArray[i] << setw(10) << studentAverage[i] << endl << endl;
}
```

^ the loop that displays the data at the end of the program.

I'll also add what the output should look like for a little clarification

```
How many students?  2
How many quizzes?  3

Enter the students name:  John Smith
Enter Quiz 1: 90
Enter Quiz 2: 80
Enter Quiz 3: 75
Enter the students name: John Jones
Enter Quiz 1: 100
Enter Quiz 2: 90
Enter Quiz 3: 80

Student              Quiz Average
---------------------------------
John Smith               81.67
John Jones               90.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can modify the below code to suit your needs. It takes a string and integer.
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
std::string name;
int num;
std::vector<std::string> stringList;
std::vector<int> intList;
while( std::cin >> name >> num )
{
    //enter stop and 0 to stop
    if (!name.compare("stop") && num == 0) break;
    stringList.push_back(name);
    intList.push_back(num);

}
std::copy(stringList.begin(), stringList.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string> (std::cout,","));
std::cout << std::endl;
std::copy(intList.begin(), intList.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout ,",") );
std::cout << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```